# Filtering objects using ActiveRecord,NHibernate, DetachedCriteria

Tags: c#, nhibernate, activerecord, filter, detachedcriteria

C# 3.0, Nhibernate 2.1.2 , Castle ActiveRecord 2.1, WinXP 32

I have a problem filtering elements with ActiveRecord and DetachedCriteria.
There are 2 tables one contains the objects to be filtered (PropertyContainer) and the other contains the values of dymamic property set for this object (PropertyValue).

```
PropertyContainer
 Id int

PropertyValue
 Id             int
 ContainerId    int
 Value          real
```

I need to select PropertyContainer object with the values from PropertyValue table matching some condition (e.g. property with Id = 1 and Value > 2). I would like to do this using DetachedCriteria, I am trying to write something like this:

```
var detachedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(PropertyContainer));

detachedCriteria.SetProjection(
    Projections.SqlProjection(@"select Value from PropertyValue where Id=1"),
    new[] { "ExternalProperty" }, 
    new[] { NHibernateUtil.Double }));  

detachedCriteria.Add(Expression.Ge("ExternalProperty",2));

var filteredItems = PropertyContainer.SlicedFindAll(0,100,detachedCriteria);
```

Then this call is executed I get the following error: 
"could not resolve property: ExternalProperty of: PropertyContainer"

The question is:

1. What is wrong with this approach ?
2. What is the right way to do filtration by dynamic property set using ActiveRecord/NHibernate and DetachedCriteria ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if PropertyValue looks like:

```
class PropertyValue
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual double Value { get; set; }
}
```

you can do:

```
DetachedCriteria.For<PropertyContainer>()
    .CreateAlias("PropertyValues", "prop")
    .Add(Restrictions.Ge("prop.Value", 2))
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("prop.Id", 1));
```